Rxjs - Using EMPTY in combination with finalize not firing
taking the following code as example:
const subject$ = new Subject();

subject$
  .pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('tap1')),
    switchMap(() => EMPTY),
    tap(() => console.log('tap2')),
    finalize(() => console.log('finalize')),
  ).subscribe();

subject$.next(null);

What i'm trying to achieve is the following output:
Expected Output:
tap1
finalize

Actual Output:
tap1

Reading what each operator does it should work as expected but it doesn't.
My thought process was:

i have a subject that emits values
i switch the observable to a new one, in this case EMPTY
Since EMPTY as per documentation emits a complete notification without emitting items i expected tap2 to not be logged and finalize to be logged since the chained observable has been completed.

I am clearly not getting it right. Could anyone help me understand the flow and how to make it work for my need please?

switchMap() emits complete notification only when both its merged Observable completes and its source Observable completes.
Since at the top of your chain you have a Subject that emits complete only when you call complete() function, switchMap() will never complete.
More detailed example: A very common use-case for switchMap() is merging an async HTTP request in for example typeahead search field like this:
fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .pipe(
        map(event => event.target.value), 
        debounceTime(500),
        switchMap(search => API call goes here),
    )
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)
    });

If switchMap() emitted complete notification when its inner Observable completed (that's when the API call ended) then this chain would search only once. However, fromEvent() never completes and that's why when you continue typing it's going to make subsequent API calls.

Thank you. I missed the fact that the source observable must complete as well for switchMap to complete. I'd like to add how i achieved my goal (my expected output).
Since my real use case is a call made on submit what i ended up doing is using take(1) to make the source obserable complete. This way when i return EMPTY the code skips directly to the finalize for cleanup.

The empty completes you are right, but that will only complete the stream, when the EMPTY is the start of the stream!
EMPTY.pipe(finalize(() => console.log('finalize'))).subscribe({
  next: () => console.log('Next'),
  complete: () => console.log('Complete!'),
});

// will output
// Complete!
// finalize

But our start of the stream is the subject$ which is not yet completed and will continue to receive events, even though mid of the stream is stopped halfway by EMPTY so the source needs to complete, then you will get the finalize and complete block triggering!
import './style.css';

import { Subject, switchMap, tap, finalize, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

const subject$ = new Subject();

subject$
  .pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('tap1')),
    switchMap(() => EMPTY),
    tap(() => console.log('tap2')),
    finalize(() => console.log('finalize'))
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: () => console.log('next'),
    error: () => console.log('error'),
    complete: () => console.log('complete'),
  });
// emits tap1
// output:
// tap1
subject$.next(null);
// emits tap 1 again eventhough empty was returned
// output:
// tap1
subject$.next(null);
// will complete the observable and give the output
// output:
// complete
// finalize

subject$.complete();

EMPTY.pipe(finalize(() => console.log('finalize'))).subscribe({
  next: () => console.log('Next'),
  complete: () => console.log('Complete!'),
});

// will output
// Complete!
// finalize

Stackblitz Demo
